# framelayout.addView(view ) overlaps/ removes toolbar?

Tags: android, android-view, android-framelayout

I want multiple activity to have same Navigation drawer ,so I created BaseDrawerActivity

in first activity: using framelayout and setContentView(activity_layout_id) I was able to get the result

in Second activity: I have to use setContentView (customView) but action bar element (HomeUpbutton) which were visible in first activity are not visible

may be overlapped by customView?

I want toolbar elements to be visible over view and view to take full space (area of toolbar as well)

**BaseDrawerActivity**

```
 public class BaseDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected DrawerLayout fullLayout;
    protected FrameLayout frameLayout;
 @Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {

    fullLayout= (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_base_drawer, null);
    frameLayout=  fullLayout.findVi

ewById(R.id.content_frame);

        // Setting the content of layout your provided to the act_content frame
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, frameLayout, true);
        super.setContentView(fullLayout);

        setUpToolBar();
    }

    private void setUpToolBar() {
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();

        if (actionbar != null) {
            actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_settings_black_24dp);
        }

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // perform whatever you want on back arrow click
//                fullLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
//                return true;

                fullLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view) {
//        super.setContentView(view);
        fullLayout= (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_base_drawer, null);
        frameLayout=  fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.content_frame);

        frameLayout.addView(view);
//        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, frameLayout, true);
        super.setContentView(fullLayout);
        setUpToolBar();
    }
}
```

**activity_base_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Use DrawerLayout as root container for activity -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Layout to contain contents of main body of screen (drawer will slide over this) -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="bottom|center">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="540dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:paddingTop="30dp" >


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text 1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text 1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/try1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**CustomView**

```
public class CustomView extends View {
    Bitmap background ;
    Rect rect;
    int dWidth,dHeight;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.background);
        Display display = ((Activity)getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        dWidth  =   size.x;
        dHeight =   size.y;
        rect    =   new Rect(0,0,dWidth,dHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(background,null,rect,null);
    }
}
```

.

**edit**

in activity_base_drawer.xml

```
<!-- Layout to contain contents of main body of screen (drawer will slide over this) -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

in BaseDrawerActivity

```
@Override
    public void setContentView(View view) {
//       super.setContentView(view);
        fullLayout= (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_base_drawer, null);
        linearLayout =  fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        framelayout=linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.framelayout);

        framelayout.addView(view);
//        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, linearLayout, true);
        super.setContentView(fullLayout);
        setUpToolBar();
    }
```

Comment: That's how FrameLayouts work. There's no alignment with respect to other children. The last-added/inflated child, or the one with the highest elevation, goes on top. Use a LinearLayout, or a different frame.

Comment: if I use linear layout i guess it will make my view go below action bar which i dont want.. so will i be able to do it using relative layout ?

Comment: Why not just use a dedicated container?

Comment: You can also `addView(View, index)`.

Comment: tried using linear layout and addview with index as well but didn't work... and I didn't get dedicated container ?

Comment: Make a `<FrameLayout>` or some other tag inside your `content_frame`, use the XML to properly align it with the Toolbar (use a LinearLayout for `content_frame` instead maybe), then inflate the content there instead.

Comment: i added the edits you suggested but still actionbar is still not visible

Comment: Show your new code.

Comment: added after edit in post  .. posted only changes made

Comment: Does the Toolbar show in the XML preview?

Comment: yes https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_G5BP1SDTOyPuTpymnTVqhVg0xIoaRJu

Comment: And you're using `setContentView(int)`, not `setContentView(View)` in your subclasses right?

Comment: I am using setContentView (view),  the one with setContentView(int) works fine, but for some reasons i need to use view

Comment: Then you need to make a custom `setContentView(View)`.

Comment: custom or override ,   i override setContentView(view) in BaseDrawerActivity

Comment: You need to override it. And I don't see it in the code you posted. You've only overridden `setContentView(int)`.

Comment: it is bottom most of BaseDrawerActivity

Comment: and after adding linear layout and all   I have added the modified code after **edit**